# How do I cd into a directory in the home folder?

Tags: command-line, directory, home-directory, cd-command

How do I change directories to downloads, from the home folder, in the latest version Ubuntu 12.10? I tried `cd /downloads`, but it gave an error saying that there is no such directory.

Answer (score 22):

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Remember: Linux is case sensitive, so `Downloads` and `downloads` are different directories.

`~` is a "shortcut" to the home directory. Another one would be `$HOME`. If you're already in your home directory you can just `cd Downloads`.

Answer (score 6):

From the `Downloads` directory, you can quickly return to your home directory by simply typing `cd` at the prompt. `cd ~` does the same thing.

There two basic ways to get around in BASH:

1. Using absolute pathnames
2. Using relative pathnames

**Absolute** pathnames start at the root directory, denoted by a leading `/`, and can be used from anywhere. To use the absolute path to go to `Downloads`, you can run:

```
cd /home/<username>/Downloads
```

where `<username>` is replaced with your username. You can also replace it with the environment variable `$USER` which usually expands to the username of the user currently running the shell. You can also replace `/home/<username>` with `$HOME`, which will usually expand to the absolute path of the home directory of the user running the shell.

A useful shortcut for this is

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

The tilde character (`~`) takes the place of `/home/<username>` - it expands to the home directory of the user currently running the shell. Note that this expansion will not be performed if the tilde character is in double or single quotes.

**Relative** pathnames start at the working directory (the one you're in). So if you know what directory you're in, you can use some shortcuts to get around. For example

- `.` (dot) refers to the current working directory
- `..` (dot)(dot) refers to the parents directory of the current working directory

when you are in your Home folder and type `cd Downloads` you could also type `./Downloads`
The `./` is implied when you just type `cd Downloads` (working directory is implied if you don't include a pathname).

When you are in the `Downloads` directory, you could also use `cd ..` to return to the parent directory `/home/<username>`. In this case it is easiest to just type `cd`, because that changes the working directory your home directory immediately wherever you are. However, the `..` becomes very useful when you are navigating around nested directory structures or other locations on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can also shorten typing by using aliases in .bash_aliases which is in your home directory. In this example, typing dwn would take you to your Download directory.

```
alias dwn='cd /home/andy/Downloads'
```

Comment: I think this conflicts with the spirit of the question. A person could have 100's of subdirectories under their $HOME and having to create 100's of acronyms and aliasing them would be cumbersome.

Comment: No conflict. I am offering help that I have received from others.