# Proper method for addressing a user's home directory

Tags: command-line, bash, home-directory

I am making a dialog menu for an Ubuntu VPN that is calling up other scripts like this:

```
cd
cd myrepo/gui
./filetocall.sh
```

The first `cd` is to ensure the directory for the second `cd` is always home.

Is there a better method I can use to address this in one line? (Without specifically naming the user in the path, so it can be installed and used on a few devices?)

Comment: Dont forget to `cd || fail` !

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: [How do I cd into a directory in the home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/262674/301745)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` (tilde) or `$HOME` can be used for getting the current user's home directory, so you could do:

```
cd ~/myrepo/gui
cd "$HOME/myrepo/gui"
```

Or even execute it directly:

```
~/myrepo/gui/filetocall.sh
"$HOME"/myrepo/gui/filetocall.sh
```

Comment: If `filetocall.sh` expects the CWD to be `~/myrepo/gui` then executing it directly could cause issues. Doing the cd and the executable call in two steps would prevent that.

Comment: @KevinJohnson That's true, though I would consider that to be a bug in `filetocall.sh`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the same method used by `login`, which avoids being fooled by redefinitions of `$HOME`:

```
homedir="$(getent passwd $( /usr/bin/id -u ) | cut -d: -f6)"
cd "$homedir"
```

Comment: What about redefinitions of `$USER`? Maybe `homedir="$(getent passwd -- "$(whoami)" | cut -d: -f6)"` ?

Comment: Well, it's not like I redefine `$HOME` often, but when I do it, it's *precisely* because I want scripts like this one to use that directory instead...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni For exactly that reason I voted on [Aviendha](https://askubuntu.com/users/894105/aviendha)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093700/284919).

Answer (score 3):

`cd ~/myrepo/gui` will do the trick, or a little longer: `cd $HOME/myrepo/gui`.

`~` is a shell shortcut for users home directory, $HOME is a variable set by th shell for the same.

Comment: Technically, it's the other way around - `~` is a shortcut for `$HOME`. If you set `HOME` to something, then `~` will take that value (test with `(HOME=foo; echo ~)` for example).